# How do I open up a page on selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)
button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("x")
button.click()
```

I have this code to open up wordle on python, but I do not know how to actually make it show the page. Please help! Also if anyone would like to help me along the process of learning how to make a bot to play wordle I would appreciate any help or tips.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong with the code, have you checked to make sure it isn't a problem with the environment or packages? What version of python are you using?

Comment: I downloaded version 3 but when i ask the version it shows 2.7, im not sure how it works

Comment: What IDE are you using, I had this same problem before.

Comment: vscode i think.